# Revmob differentiate video or static interstitial in AdDidReceive

Tags: unity-game-engine, revmob, revmobads

How to differentiate whether or not cached video is static interstitial fullscreen or video ad in AdDidReceive delegate method???

```
public void AdDidReceive (string revMobAdType)
{
    if( revMobAdType == ?? ) {} //video or static interstitial
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The interstitial ad can receive static images or videos (you can configure this behaviour  if you go to Media -> Click your Media -> Ad Units -> Click on your "Fullscreen" ad unit "Edit" button -> Check if it accepts video).

The possible values for revMobAdType may be: "Link", "Banner" and "Fullscreen", so I'd recommend doing something like:

```
switch (revMobAdType) {
    case "Link":
        break;
    case "Fullscreen":
        break;
    case "Banner":
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

To check for Video or RewardedVideo, use:

```
public void VideoLoaded () {
    Debug.Log("VideoLoaded.");
}
public void RewardedVideoLoaded () {
    Debug.Log("RewardedVideoLoaded.");
}
```

Check [RevMob's Unity Listener docs](https://www.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/sdk/unity#content-listeners) for more information.

Comment: For static and video interstitial, revMobAdType will be "Fullscreen" right ?

Comment: Yes, there is no difference between static and video interstitial atm

Comment: It would be very helpful if you guys could implement functionality something similar to this

switch (revMobAdType) {
    case "Link":
        break;
    case "Fullscreen":
        break;
    case "Video":
        break;
    case "Banner":
        break;
    default:
        break;
}